# Poorly Painted Rebus (3)

Tags: rebus

[image]

This creature is a...
<sub>The answer to this riddle is a common object, being, phrase, or idiom</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is it a

> sunfish?

because

> sun.... fish....

Comment: I submit rot13(lryybj yvtugohyo jvgu rlrf)

Comment: I submit rot13(ceboyrz sbe gur cynargf fgnaqvat hcjvaq.) :|